# Using sleep and select with signals

Tags: c, signals, sleep, select-function

I want to use the `select()` function to wait for 1 second, as my program uses signals to control stuff, so `sleep()` would return prematurely. The weird thing is that when using `select()` it also returns prematurely.

I am calling select like this

```
struct timeval timeout;    
timeout.tv_sec = 10;  
timeout.tv_usec = 1000000; 
select (0 ,NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
```

but whenever a signal arrives, it returns (I am using a nano second timer for the signal)

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
struct timespec timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 10;
timeout.tv_nsec = 0;
while (nanosleep(&timeout, &timeout) && errno == EINTR);
```

The "remaining time" pointer to `nanosleep` will take care of letting you restart the sleep with the necessary amount of remaining time if it gets interrupted.

Comment: I'll give it a try on monday when I get my computer charger back, but this should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`man 7 signal` says:

> Interruption of System Calls and Library Functions by Signal Handlers
>
> If a signal handler is invoked while a system call or  library 
>   function  call  is  blocked,  then
>   either:
>
> ```
>    * the call is automatically restarted after the signal handler
>      returns; or
>
>    * the call fails with the error EINTR.
> ```
>
> Which of these two behaviors occurs depends on the interface and
>   whether or not the signal handler
>              was established using the SA_RESTART flag (see sigaction(2)). 
>   The details vary across  UNIX  sys‐
>              tems; below, the details for Linux.
>
> If  a blocked call to one of the following interfaces is
>   interrupted by a signal handler, then
>   the
>              call will be automatically restarted after the signal handler
>   returns if the SA_RESTART  flag  was
>              used; otherwise the call will fail with the error EINTR

Generally, checking if the return value is -1 and errno == EINTR and then re-calling the function is the right way to correct for this.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and not OP's issue. Linux has the sane BSD behavior for signals (restartable syscalls), but `select` *always* returns when interrupted by a signal, even if the signal handler is installed with `SA_RESTART`, as a *feature*. The idea is that the program may (probably does) want to act on the receipt of a signal just like it would act on file descriptors ready for IO.

Comment: I think this is the explanation for the second answer's implementation. What I am doing is using a signal to track time, trying to mimic a microprocessor's clock interrupt interface. So the signal actually gets called every nanosecond, incrementing a time counter. Is this a bad way of doing it? There may be 100s of processes running at the same time using the exact same signal.

I am using a timer created with timer_create and CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID for clockid_t