# convert timeval structure to c#

Tags: c#, c++, timeval

I know this question may be so simple, I have the following code and it should be converted to C#, but the main problem is that I can not understand what below code is doing exactly!!!!...I've searched but I did not find any thing..I Think may be the `timeval structure` and the `select function` can be removed with out any consequences!! Am I right?? If no, then How can I convert it to C#??? what is the responsibility of `select function` exactly??
thanks in advanced.

```
void WaitMs(UInt32 milliSeconds)
    {
        //start of problem
        struct timeval t=
        { milliSeconds/1000, 
          (milliSeconds%1000)*1000 
        };
        Select(0,NULL,NULL,NULL,&t);
        UInt32 temp=milliSeconds;
     //end of problem
        Logger.NewWait(temp);
    }
```

I think the code between start of problem and end of problem is not necessary at all! true??

Comment: **C# != C++ != C**!!! Please specify a language of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time and date values are always transferred **by milliseconds value**.

For **C#**:

- To get a time span from milliseconds, use [`TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.frommilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- To get a date and time from milliseconds, use `DateTime.Parse` [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336932/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-format-in-c)

In C++ [there is also a way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728068/how-to-calculate-a-time-difference-in-c).

In C#, causing a delay, as `Select` function does in your code, is made by `Thread.Sleep` call.

Comment: Thanks Elliot, but Could you please tell me what does exactly select function do in the WaitMs function?

Comment: Usage of this function is [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198560/using-sleep-and-select-with-signals). Shortly, it is used to **cause a delay**

Comment: Is there any function in c# which is equivalent to select in c++ ??